# Java print dialog takes significant time to show

Tags: java, printing, citrix, printers, printdialog

on a Citrix server we have a Java SE application that brings a v6 JRE, and a few other applications such as MS Office.
Now we experience that the Java application takes a significant time to show the Print dialog when a user click on the Print menu function (up to 1 minute or longer).
In other applications the dialog shows within seconds.
From a user standpoint the printers on this Citrix server constitute from a few system printers (such as PDF printer) and the user's local client printers mapped into the session by Citrix technology. Those client printers can be client-local or network printers.

What can be possible reasons why the Java app takes that long to show the dialog?
Does Java make availability checks in the background or somehow other connect to the printers before it shows the dialog?
Is there a chance for a setting that can speed-up things, skip checks etc.?

Thanks a lot,
Andy

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Answering a question like this is difficult; more details are needed from my point of view. There can be many reasons why X in Java is slowed down (e.g. available memory for the JVM). A print dialog in Java doesn't do any network calls (like checking for printer availability) unless it was developed/implemented in that way. How was/is the print dialog implemented? Also ``Now we experience...`` does that mean it worked fine before? If so, what changed since then?

Comment: Also, ___your question may be more suitable for a different Stack Exchange site, like [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com)___? Searching may turn up an answer there? For example [Performance problems when running Java desktop applications on Citrix Metaframe](https://serverfault.com/q/49487) – note that I cannot really judge whether that linked Q/A is what you're looking for. Have a go at it yourself.

Comment: Finally check [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what topics are good to be asked here on StackOverflow.